# Show that a function $f(z)$ holomorphic on an open set $\Omega$ cannot have $|f(a + bi)|^2$ = $\frac{K}{cosha}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can we show that a function $f(z)$ holomorphic on an open set $\Omega$ cannot have $|f(a + bi)|^2$ = $\frac{K}{cosha}$ for all $a + bi \in \Omega$, where $K \neq 0$ is a real constant? Please try to keep answers elementary, without using integration.

Comment: let $g(z)  =\log f(z)$ . $Re( g(z) )$ is constant on every line $Re(z) = a$, hence all the derivatives of $g(z)$ are purely real, a contradiction with $g(z)$ is holomorphic and not constant

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand on why this means all the derivatives of $g$ are real?

Comment: $g'(z) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{g(z+i\epsilon)-g(z)}{i \epsilon}$ (and I meant a contradiction with $g(z)$ is holomorphic and not of the form $a+bz$ @Winther )

Comment: Why does $g(z)$ not being of the form $a + bz$ matter?

Comment: Would you mind putting this in some more detail? I have no experience with ODEs. Also if you could explain what's wrong with @user1952009's solution I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @Winther it is better to prove the only holomorphic function that are purely real (or imaginary) are constant. $\forall z, Im(h(z)) = 0 \implies \forall z, Im(h'(z)) = 0$ , but then $h(z_0+i \epsilon) \sim h(z_0) + i \epsilon h'(z_0)$ whose imaginary part is $\sim \epsilon h'(z_0)$, a contradiction with $Im(h(z)) = 0$ if $h'(z_0) \ne 0$. This being true for every $z_0$, you have $\forall z, h'(z) = 0$, i.e. $h(z)$ is constant

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was it. We haven't done analyticity of holomorphic functions yet so I would need to show that to complete the answer.

Comment: @Vik78 Yes, I used the holomorphy of the derivative (existence of the 2nd complex derivative) and the fact $\log f(z)$ is holomorphic

Comment: So you showed that the derivative of log $f(z)$ is constant. Explicitly, how does that contradict $g(z)$ being holomorphic and nonconstant?

Comment: come  on. From $\log f(z) = C$ I'm sure you can finish

Comment: Like I said, no integration in this class yet. I could just submit it as is but I'd rather find a way around using it. Also you showed $g'(z)$ is constant, not $g(z)$ is constant.

Comment: I found it without the holomorphic/analytic theorem : replace the derivative of $g(z) = \log f(z)$ by $h(z)  = i(g(z)-g(z+i a))$, it is also holomorphic and purely real and hence its derivative vanishes

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the more general problem of determining all differentiable functions $g(x)$ that are such that there exist a homomorphic function $f(z)$ satisfying
$$|f(x+iy)| = g(x)$$

Before we start I should warn that this solution cannot be said to be "elementary, without using integration". Lets start by writing $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$. We then have

$$|f(z)|^2 = g^2(x) \implies u^2(x,y) + v^2(x,y)  = g^2(x)$$

Taking partial derivatives of this equation with respect to $x$ and $y$ gives us

$$u u_y + vv_y = 0~~~~\text{and}~~~uu_x + vv_x = g(x)g'(x)$$

Now if $f$ is holomorphic then the [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) can be used to simplify the equations above. The first equation gives us
$$\frac{u_x}{u} = \frac{v_x}{v} \implies v(x,y) = u(x,y) F(y)$$
for some differentiable function $F(y)$. The second equation gives us
$$u^2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{v}{u}\right) = \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}(u^2+v^2) \implies F'(y) = \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\left(1+F^2(y)\right)$$

and by integrating we get

$$F(y) = \tan\left(\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}y + C\right)$$

for some constant $C$. Since $F(y)$ is a function of $y$ only we must have $\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} = b$ for some real constant $b$ which gives us that $g(x)$ has to be on the form $g(x) = e^{a+bx}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.